# Displaying the values of the wrapper class

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

**I have a wrapper class inside a wrapper class which contains Assignment object and List of Projects.**

```
public class projWrapper{
    public Professional_Experience__c peWrap {get;set;}
    public List<assignmentWrapper> assignmentListWrapper1 {get;set;}
}

public class assignmentWrapper{
    public Assignment__c assignmentWrap1{get;set;}
    public List<Project__c> projectforassignmentWrap {get;set;}
}
```

**I want to show the certain *Assignment/s* within a *Professional Experience* and the certain *Project/s* within an *Assignment*. How can I achieve this?**

[image]

Controller

**I've made this code but when showing the result to the Visualforce page, it displays all the *Assignments* in every *Professional Experience* and all the *Projects* in every *Assignment*.**

```
contactRecord = [SELECT Name, Email, HomePhone, MobilePhone FROM Contact WHERE ID =: thisContact.Id];
profExperienceList = [SELECT Id, Employee_ID__r.Name, Job_Title__c,Name,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c, STRING_Start_Date__c, STRING_End_Date__c, Job_Description__c, White_Label__c, (SELECT Company_Id__c, Name, White_Label__c, Description__c, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, STRING_Start_Date__c, STRING_End_Date__c FROM Projects__r) FROM Professional_Experience__c WHERE Employee_ID__c =: contactRecord.Id ORDER BY Start_Date__c DESC LIMIT 3];
assignmentList = [SELECT Company_ID__c,End_Date__c,Name,Start_Date__c,Job_Title__c, STRING_Start_Date__c, STRING_End_Date__c FROM Assignment__c WHERE Company_ID__c IN : profExperienceList ORDER BY Start_Date__c DESC];
projectforassignmentList = [SELECT Name, Company_Id__c, Company_Id__r.Id, Company_Id__r.Name, Company_Id__r.Job_Description__c,Description__c, End_Date__c, Start_Date__c, White_Label__c, STRING_Start_Date__c, STRING_End_Date__c, Assignment_ID__c  FROM Project__c WHERE Assignment_Id__c IN :assignmentList ORDER BY Start_Date__c DESC];

projListWrapper = new List<projWrapper>();
listofAssignmentWrapper = new List<assignmentWrapper>();

for(Professional_Experience__c profExperience : profExperienceList){
    pw = new projWrapper();
    List<Project__c> listofProjectforAssignment = new List<Project__c>();

    for(Assignment__c assignment : assignmentList){
       if(profExperience.Id == assignment.Company_ID__c){
           alwra = new assignmentWrapper();
           alwra.assignmentWrap1 = assignment;
           for(Project__c projectforassignment : projectforassignmentList){
               if(assignment.Id == projectforassignment.Assignment_ID__c){
                   listofProjectforAssignment.add(projectforassignment);
               }
           }
           alwra.projectforassignmentWrap = listofProjectforAssignment;
           listofAssignmentWrapper.add(alwra);
        }
    }
    pw.peWrap = profExperience;
    pw.assignmentListWrapper1 = listofAssignmentWrapper;
    projListWrapper.add(pw);
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve the picture above? Thanks!

Comment: The way you have prepared the list, same way loop through the <apex:repeat> and put <ul><li> properly to generate hierarchy

Comment: Strictly speaking, you could have done this all in one query without a wrapper at all.

Comment: Do you mean @SantanuBoral , that I have something wrong when displaying it in the visualforce page?

Comment: How can I do it @sfdcfox ?

Comment: I'm having some challenge reading your code, but basically query the middle object, its parent fields, as necessary, and its related children as a subquery.

Comment: @JMRAF I was talking about to create a treeview you have to use HTML tag <ul> <li> properly. Some sample I can find here http://blog.biswajeetsamal.com/post/2014/08/07/salesforce-how-to-craete-treeview-in-visualforce-page/

Comment: You should post your VF page code as well, not entire page, only the related part will do.

Comment: Thank you for all your reply but I've referenced some code in here -
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159933/i-have-a-parent-child-grandchild-i-need-one-object-constructed-and-returned?answertab=active#tab-top