# Posting multiple values using Apex Rest callout with POST method

Tags: apex, integration, rest

I am learning Integration from this [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts)

Pre-existing JSON at the endpoint

```
{"animals":["majestic badger","fluffy bunny","scary bear","chicken"]}
```

Code that i have written to add three more elements to animals

```
        HTTP container = new HTTP();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setBody('{"name": ["mighty moose","mighty","moose"]}');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        HttpResponse response = container.send(request);
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 201){
            System.debug(response.getBody());
            System.debug(response.getStatus());
        }else{
            System.debug(response.getStatusCode());
            System.debug(response.getStatus());
        }
```

By executing the above code I'm getting the following response that is that the whole value **["mighty moose","mighty","moose"]** is getting inserted as one value

```
{"animals":["majestic badger","fluffy bunny","scary bear","chicken",["mighty moose","mighty","moose"]]}
```

But i want the output to be that each value to get inserted as three different values in a single web callout

```
{"animals":["majestic badger","fluffy bunny","scary bear","chicken","mighty moose","mighty","moose"]}
```

If I change the body as

```
request.setBody('{"name": "mighty moose","name":"mighty","name":"moose"}');
```

Only the last one is getting added rather than all 3

```
{"animals":["majestic badger","fluffy bunny","scary bear","chicken","moose"]}
```

Comment: Is the endpoint a salesforce rest resource that you control? If not then not sure we can help much without details on the endpoint. If it is, posting that code would help provide clarity otherwise all we have is a question with unrelated working code. [Ask]

Comment: @Eric Actually I am learning Integration from Trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts So i was hitting the server that they have given which is on heroku platform So it had the example to insert 1 value so was trying to add in multiple values like insert an array of objects rather than one

Comment: I added that to your question. In future add clarity in the question itself not in the comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer would be *if the remote service was able to process it* would be to post the object array.

```
[{"name": "mighty moose"},{"name": "dumb moose"}]
```

results in a response of

> USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|{"animals":["majestic badger","fluffy
>   bunny","scary bear","chicken",null]}

The problem is that the service is only set up to accept a single value not an array so you will not be able to do it given the current state of the external service

```
{"name":"mighty moose", "name":"dull"}
```

Is **not valid JSON** as there are duplicate keys. The service does process it however and stores the last value `dull` in the returned results

Attempts at multiple calls will overwrite your previous addition. It appears from my tests at least that you can add one and only one to the list.

Remember, the trailhead is setup to perform a specific task. Anything outside of what is explicitly outlined *may* not work

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I have answered this question which will help you to understand how JSON stores the Array of objects. In that example,

- Parent is Account
- Child is Opportunity
- Grand Child is Task

[I have a Parent->Child->GrandChild .. I need one object constructed and returned for a rest call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159933/i-have-a-parent-child-grandchild-i-need-one-object-constructed-and-returned)

[image: rest testing]

So you need to prepare multiple records like this:

```
[{"name": "mighty moose"},{"name": "dumb moose"}]
```

Though Eric has correctly mentioned in this answer that "*The problem is that the service is only set up to accept a single value not an array so you will not be able to do it given the current state of the external service*"

Comment: This does not work in the context of the question. The JSON is valid but the service is not set up to handle it

Comment: @Eric That's true, you have already given that answer

Comment: Yup. It could be made highly useful if you detail how a JSON Array of objects is constructed focusing on the OP question rather than details that are out of context. Otherwise it is just repeating what has already been said...

Answer (score -2):

Try to escape the quotes: `req.setBody('{\"name:\" \"value\"}');`

Comment: But how to do for multiple values you have just given for one

Comment: Did it work? Why are people down voting? I notice from the post above that you have a duplicated key as well, so it would be something like:

`req.setBody(JSON.serialize('{"name": "mighty moose","name":"mighty"}'))`

Comment: @DuduNato - Because Your answer is not correct as it is a single value and your JSON in the comment  is not valid as You have duplicate keys (name). Seems you did not do your research before posting the answer yet you chastise the OP for the same thing

Comment: @Eric I got miss understood since I'm new in the site :)

Yes, you are right the json is wrong. But it won't work if he doesn't serialize it. When I meant research it wasn't in a sarcastic way.

Comment: @DuduNato - The JSON will work just fine without serializing it. In fact, serializing it will cause a 400 response. Appreciate your participation so please do continue. A bit of research into answers will benefit everyone. Downvotes are not meant to be punitive, rather they are meant to make you and others aware that the solution provided may not be complete or valid. Please take it as an opportunity to expand your knowledge

Comment: @Eric interesting! Good to know!